# Is there a Hive equivalent of SQL “ LIKE '_Z_%' ESCAPE '%' ”

Tags: syntax, hive

While Hive supports LIKE queries: ex.

```
select last_name from employee WHERE  last_name LIKE '_Z_%';
```

Hive Does not support  LIKE with ESCAPE queries: ex.

```
select last_name from employee WHERE  last_name LIKE '_Z_%' ESCAPE '%';
```

Does anyone know an equivalent solution that Hive does support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive does support such queries using **rlike**. You can specify any regex and instead of `%`, you have to use `.*`

Try something like this

```
select last_name from employee WHERE  last_name rlike '_Z_.*';
```

Comment: Yes ,I can use either `A [NOT] RLIKE B` OR  `A REGEXP B` form to achieve this.  Ultimately I have to derive equivalent Regex of it.